# Loop with particular assigned numbers

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

May be below question might be very basic but I searched internet but did not get the answer. So I felt stack Overflow is the right place.

I would like to run for loop in "R" with specific numbers.

```
ex: aa <- c(4,6,8,9)

for (i in aa) print("test")

Note: when I run loop it will run/print for 4 times only.
```

But I want numbers in vector should be parameter for loop

```
Expected:

ex: aa <- c(4,6,8,9)

for (i in aa) print("test")

in place of aa we should get 4 . so test will print 4 times. Later 6 then again it need to print 6 times etc.
```

Comment: Please do not spam language tags.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rep`

```
for(i in aa) print(rep("test", i))
```

Or may be with `strrep`

```
for(i in aa) print(strrep("test", i))
```